# Approval Process Email Notification

Tags: approval-process

I have an approval process with 13 steps with some approvers routed to queues and other steps that route to a single user and still others that route to a combination of both individual users and queues where the step requires unanimous approval. When the record is submitted for approval, does an email automatically get sent to the approvers...i.e. Queue/User? Or, do you have to define a step action to send an email notification? I thought the email gets automatically sent, but I'm not getting any email notification. I also want to be able to approve directly from the email without logging into the system. If the emails should go out automatically, any thoughts of what might be causing the emails to not be sent? Deliverability is currently set to "System Only". Does it have to be set to "All Email" instead? Thanks.

Comment: Yes deliverability needs to be all email for approval notifications to be sent.  For users, they will be notified automatically, but i believe there is a user preference they can use to disable notifications. For queues, may depends on queue email settings but not positive on that one, will test.

Comment: See this article, confirms the user preference to receive approval notifications https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_change_approval_user_pref.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: And this article has all of the details on email notification to queues https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_considerations_approver.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Thanks @gorav...that's what I needed!